# How many significant figures are needed in base 2?

Tags: approximation

$x \in \mathbb{R}$

$2^{500}<x<2^{501} $

How many significant figures are needed in base 2, to know in high approximation whether $2^x$ is integer?

Comment: What does it mean to "know in high approximation whether $2^x$ is integer"? Whether $2^x$ is integer is either true or false, and supposing you don't consider "true" to be a high approximation of "false" or vice versa, you need to know exactly. Also, unless you know $x$ exactly (or you know for instance that $x$ is integer), you will _never_ be able to tell for sure that $2^x$ is integer.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I mean that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, 2^x - 2^{-500}<n<2^x + 2^{-500}$

Comment: What is the motivation?

Comment: @lhf, To know how many bit I will need to calculate of x.

Comment: Question is very close to a cross-post on [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1950/276).

Comment: @GeoffOxberry, do I have to delete one of the questions?

Comment: @Must: I don't know yet. Let me consult with the math mods.

Comment: @Geoff: the questions are very similar, but I think we have the better answer here right now. I am not sure if we need to migrate. But if you feel the need, I would prefer if you migrate it if this one is the main one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to estimate the $\delta$ such that $2^{x+\delta} - 2^x = 1$. This means $2^\delta = 1+\dfrac{1}{2^x}$, so that $\delta$ might be estimated as $\dfrac{1}{2^x \times \ln2}$, or, taking the upper bound for $x$, $\delta$ might be estimated as $\dfrac{1}{2^{501} \times \ln2}$.

The number of required significant digits (after the decimal point) is about $-\log_{10}\delta = \log_{10}(2^{501}) + \log_{10}\ln2$, which is about 151, plus-minus a digit. Or, if you're working in base 2, the number of required significant digits is about $-\log_{2}\delta = \log_{2}(2^{501}) + \log_{2}\ln2$, which is about 502.

Given such a number of digits after the decimal point, changing the remaining digits won't change $2^x$ by more than $1$, so that, if $2^x$ is an integer, you can say what integer it is.

However, it is impossible to tell for sure whether $2^x$ is an integer, given only its rounded value, independent of the accuracy, as adding a small value beyond the accuracy limits to $x$ will turn $2^x$ from integer to non-integer and vice versa.

Comment: $\drfac{x}{y}$ doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Of course that `\drfac` would not work, but I was hoping that the obvious typo will be obvious to you as well (at least now when I re-read my comment and notice that typo).

Comment: You might want to consider using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` because that would make the fraction somewhat more readable.

Comment: I'm just not a TeX expert :)

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{2^x \times \ln2} \neq \dfrac{1}{2^{501} \times \ln2}$

Comment: $2^{500}<x<2^{501}$

Comment: @Must The task is to estimate the number of digits. $\dfrac{1}{2^{501}\times\ln 2} \leq \dfrac{1}{2^x\times\ln 2}$.

Comment: @penartur: the upper bound for $x$ should equal $2^{501}$, not $501$

Answer (score -1):

For $2^x$ to be an integer where x has a finite decimal representation, x must also be an integer. Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is not correct... any positive integer has a logarithm to the base 2, which need not be an integer.

Comment: Yes, but it will in general be an irrational number and you will not be able to distinguish it from a rational number in a finite decimal representation.

Comment: +1: @Wonder should edit his post to reflect the finite representation problem.

Comment: Ok I edited it accordingly.